Movie ending: man shot to death by couple while camera records everything
I saw the tail-end of a movie at a friend's house during the '90s, and it's stuck with me ever since. Its original language was English. A man begs a heavily armed couple (man, woman) for his life. After a few minutes of this, they shoot him to death. The man then puts his arm around the woman's shoulders (or vice versa) and they saunter off, leaving the dead man propped up against a tree. The last thing we see is a video camera on the ground nearby, which has filmed everything.
As the credits rolled, I turned to my friend's older sister and said, "But the mean people with the guns get caught, right?" and she said, "No, they don't." Needless to say, I was a bit traumatized. Just wondering if anyone knows what this movie is.

They get away with it because Stone made them the heroes to make a point. Sorry. ;)

This is the ending of Oliver Stone's Natural Born Killers (1994) with  Woody Harrelson & Juliette Lewis.

Mickey Knox and Mallory Wilson aren't your typical lovers - after killing her abusive father, they go on a road trip where, every time they stop somewhere, they kill pretty well everyone around them. They do however leave one person alive at every shootout to tell the story and they soon become a media sensation thanks to sensationalized reporting. Told in a highly visual style.

They're followed by journalist Wayne Gale (Robert Downey Jr.) who documents them, and in the end:

Escaping to a rural location, they give a final interview to Gale, whose ear they have seemingly removed (implied, but as a camera track reveals), before they tell him he must die also. He attempts various arguments to change their minds, finally appealing to their trademark practice of leaving one survivor; Mickey informs him they are leaving a witness to tell the tale, his camera.

You can see the ending here, and here's the trailer:




A mystery solved! Walt, thank you so much. I have to say the ending is still as traumatic to watch now as it was when I was 10.

Yeah, this film's no picnic... Glad you found it, anyway.
